# Reading a line ending with a newline character from a file descriptor

Tags: c, homework

I'm implementing a function that behaves like `getline()` which reads a line from file descriptor and returns the results without `\n`. allowed functions, `read()`, `free()` and `malloc`. Please review my code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef GET_C_BUFF_SIZE
# define GET_C_BUFF_SIZE 1023
#endif
#ifndef BUFF_SIZE
# define BUFF_SIZE 32
#endif

void    *my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char       *n_dest;
    const unsigned char *n_src;

    n_dest = (unsigned char *)dest;
    n_src = (unsigned char *)src;
    while (n--)
        *n_dest++ = *n_src++;
    *(++n_dest) = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

void    *my_realloc(void *ptr, size_t len)
{
    void    *real;

    real = malloc(len);
    if (real)
        my_memcpy(real, ptr, len);
    free(ptr);
    return (real);
}

int my_getchar(const int fd)
{
    static char buff[GET_C_BUFF_SIZE];
    static char *chr;
    static int  pos = 0;
    static int  ret = 0;

    if (pos >= ret)
    {
        if ((ret = read(fd, buff, GET_C_BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            chr = buff;
            pos = 0;
            return (*(chr + pos++));
        }
        else
            return (0);
    }
    else
        return (*(chr + pos++));
}

int read_line(char *text, int buf_size, char **line, const int fd)
{
    int     position;
    int     c;

    position = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        c = my_getchar(fd);
        if (c == 0 || c == '\n')
        {
            text[position] = '\0';
            *line = text;
            return (1);
        }
        else
            text[position] = c;
        position++;
        if (position >= buf_size)
        {
            buf_size += BUFF_SIZE;
            text = my_realloc(text, buf_size);
            if (!text)
                return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (1);
}

int get_line(const int fd, char **line)
{
    char    *text;
    int     buf_size;

    buf_size = BUFF_SIZE;
    text = malloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size);
    if (fd < 0 || !text || !line)
        return (-1);
    return (read_line(text, buf_size, line, fd));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Static buffer

In `my_getchar()`, you use a static buffer `buff` along with some other static variables.  The problem with this is that you can no longer call `get_line()` on two different files at the same time.  For example, if you did this:

```
get_line(fd1, &line1);
get_line(fd2, &line2);
```

Then the second `get_line()` would actually read characters from the first file descriptor, because you have buffered its contents in the static buffer.

#### Reallocation strategy

Your current reallocation strategy is to increase the size of the buffer by `BUFF_SIZE` when you run out of space.  This causes your function to have a \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity.  It would be better if you doubled the size of your buffer instead of adding a constant to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid using a standard library-like name `memcpy()` and then performing a non-intuitive functionality.  `mem...()` functions do not do anything special about a terminating null character.

   ```
   void *my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
     ...
     *(++n_dest) = '\0';  //  <-- ????
   }
   ```
2. Bug:  Insufficient memory allocation.

   ```
   // my_memcpy() affects len+1 bytes
   real = malloc(len);
   if (real)
     my_memcpy(real, ptr, len);
   ```
3. `()` not needed.

   ```
   // return (dest);
   return dest;
   ```
4. Strange default buffer size 1023.  For efficient reading of files, more common to use a power-of-2.  Not likely to make much difference though on systems that perform `"\r\n"` to `"\n"` translation.

   ```
   #ifndef GET_C_BUFF_SIZE
   # define GET_C_BUFF_SIZE 1023
   ```
5. As mentioned [@JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135137/29485), using a `static` buffer space is a questionable design practice.  Better to pass in a pointer to a structure with the needed variables.
6. Code can't seem to decide if it should use `int`, `size_t` for array indexing.  Best to use `size_t` throughout.  Return value from `read()` should be `ssize_t`.
7. `int my_getchar(const int fd)` returns 0 to indicate end-of-file, yet also returns a `char` - whihc could have the value of 0. This `getchar`-like function should 1) return a value different from a `char` to indicate end-of-file.  2) best to mimic `getchar()` and return `EOF` on end-of-file or `[0...UCHAR_MAX]`.
8. `int read_line(char *text, int buf_size, char **line, const int fd)`
    fails to indicate when end-of-file was reached as opposed to end-of-line

   ```
   c = my_getchar(fd);
   if (c == 0 || c == '\n') {
     // add
     if (c == 0 && position == 0) return end-of_file_indication;

     text[position] = '\0';
     *line = text;
     return 1;
   }
   ```
9. If an `if()` blocks ends with `return`, no need for `else`

   ```
   if (c == 0 || c == '\n') {
      text[position] = '\0';
      *line = text;
      return (1);
   }
   // else
   text[position] = c;
   ```
10. Allocate to the size of the de-referenced variable, not type.  It is easier to code, maintain, review and not mess up.

    ```
    // text = malloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size);
    text = malloc(sizeof *text * buf_size);
    ```
11. Consider not declaring a variable until it is needed.  Easier to maintain.  Eliminate uninitialized variables.

    ```
    // char    *text;
    // int     buf_size;
    // buf_size = BUFF_SIZE;
    // text = malloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size);
    int buf_size = BUFF_SIZE;
    char *text = malloc(sizeof *text * buf_size);
    ```
12. Unclear or wrong code.  When `text == NULL`, it means out-of memory *or* the size allocated was 0.  rather than use naked `-1`, use a macro or at least a component.

    ```
    #define ERROR_OOM -1
       ...
       text = my_realloc(text, buf_size);
       // if (!text)
       if (!text && buf_size == 0)
            // return (-1);
            return ERROR_OOM;
    ```
13. Consider adding `{}`.  Less likely to code incorrectly, easier to maintain.

    ```
       if (!text && buf_size == 0) {
            return (-1);
       }
    ```
14. Memory leak.  Should `fd < 0 || !line`, then allocated memory is lost.

    ```
    text = malloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size);
    if (fd < 0 || !text || !line)
      return (-1);
    ```